# Некорректное отображение шрифта с Google fonts

Tags: css, вёрстка, шрифты, google-fonts

На мобильном Lenovo старой модели шрифт на сайте отображается некорректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой мелкий и разряженный — это "Open Sans". До этого такой проблемы на телефонах и браузерах не наблюдала. Не могу понять - как это решить.

Шрифт подключается ссылкой в header:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Пробовала вариант @import и @font-face, не дало результатов.

Comment: _мобильном Леново старой модели_ - а браузер поддерживает?

Comment: Модель Lenovo a526, а браузер встроенный 4.2.2-lv81.0.031.00

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, с поддержкой кириллицы:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,600,700&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```